# Codesigning A Driver

Tags: 64-bit, driver, code-signing, code-signing-certificate

I have a program and installer that installs a driver on the users system for the program to use. However, it doesn't work on 64 bit systems.

As I understand it, I need to sign the driver to allow it to be installed. I have a code signing certificate.

How do I sign the driver with it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do cross-signing http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg487315.aspx

It's the same as signing. Don't let people tell you it has to be Verisign or whatever. It doesn't. But it does have to be a cert on Microsoft's list (see the link).